# Element alignment with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie with HTML and CSS. I'm struggling with (horizontal) element alignement and I would appreciate any help provided. 
This is what I got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/vayacondios2015/umpk0xht/

HTML

```
<div class="mainbody">
    <h2>This is uppercase title</h2>

    <div class="right">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp">Link1</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp">Link2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <form>
        <label for="textarea">This is a comment about textarea</label><br>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Example" autofocus required></textarea><br>
        <label for="textarea"><span>Note</span>: You can only use <span>this</span> word in textarea!</label><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"><br><br>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp">Link3</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select><option>Select1</option></select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select><option>Select2</option></select><br><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainbody">
    <a href="#TOP">TOP</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      
    <img><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"> Home</a><br>
    &copy;Company
</div>
```

CSS in a link jsfiddle above (couldn't attach it properly).

This is how I would like it to be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCWcL.jpg + centered on the page.

I'm looking forward for **HTML semantic correction** also, if you have some extra time and will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend getting to grips with HTML and CSS. I won't add specific links as there are thousands upon thousands of excellent resources all over the web.

However to help you I have modified the HTML so it's a little more structured:

```
<div class="mainbody">
    <h2>This is uppercase title</h2>

    <div class="right">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp">Link1</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp">Link2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <form>
        <label for="textarea" class="form-label">This is a comment about textarea</label><br>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Example" autofocus required></textarea>
        <span class="note"><strong>Note</strong>: You can only use <strong>this</strong> word in textarea!</span><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit"><br><br>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp">Link3</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select><option>Select1</option></select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select><option>Select2</option></select><br><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainbody">
    <a href="#TOP">TOP</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      
    <img><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"> Home</a><br>
    &copy;Company
</div>
```

You'll notice that the text area has a class, the note that appears under it also has been put into a span. I felt it better to use the `<strong>` tag when highlighting the bold text. You could go one step further and add a class in your CSS just for bold text. That will allow for re-usability.

I altered the CSS so that the container div which has `.mainbody` has the text aligned in the center. The rest of the changes are:

```
div.mainbody
{
    text-align: center;
}

div.mainbody h2{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

div div.right{
    text-align: right;
    float:  right;    
}

div div.left form label{
    text-align: left;
}

.form-label, .note
{
    float: left;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}

.submit {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

I think that satisfies your picture. Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/phyjauhc/1/

Comment: Double thanks for answering and correcting my HTML. I forgot to put button "Submit" on image, it should be in the middle, that's why I will add just slight correction to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/vayacondios2015/mh4m1395/

Answer (score 3):

Try these css. I will help you  check this link https://jsfiddle.net/35sgma83/

```
.middle {
  text-align: center;
}
div.mainbody {
  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to put button "Submit" on image, it should be in the middle, that's why I will add just slight correction of your code:http://jsfiddle.net/vayacondios2015/qp8r1Ld3/

Comment: I'd argue whether this is the correct way of handling centering items. If you want semantic code which makes logically sense this code shouldn't be used. The above code should only be used to center text, not elements. I still think you need to use floating, margins, widths to correctly achieve a valid semantic solution.

Comment: @ArminderDahul, what you said and as far as I have seen from some tutorials, your words sounds logical to me, and thats why I will follow your example.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML semantic correction

Can be done via the [w3c Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options)

Comment: Thnx, I will check this out!

Answer (score 0):

Add below css

```
div.middle {
  text-align: center;
}
div.ft_body {
  text-align: center;

}
```

And change bottom `div` class name to `ft_body` and update `cols="80"` to `cols="100%"` for textarea

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work properly, but thank you for the effort.